# How can i read a file until a specific line in c++

Tags: c++, file, codeblocks, variable-assignment

I am new to programming. Please help me out with the following:
I have a file: `Subtraction.txt`

There are subtitles like: Introduction, Part 1, Part 2,...

Is there a possible way to read from the file until Part 1, displays the content of the file, then it continues reading from that place and so on? 
The `nooflines` can be ignored!

```
ifstream in("C:\\Users\\Nusrat\\Desktop\\Subtraction.txt");
if(!in) {
    cout << "Cannot open input file";
    return 1;
}

string line;
while(getline(in, line))
{
    cout<<line<<endl;
    nooflines += 1;
}

in.close();
cout<<nooflines<<endl;
```

Comment: If you know when it should start and when it should stop, just write in conditions to detect that.

Comment: You already know how to read and display lines from the file.  All you need to do is look at what those lines contain and act on that. `std::string` has `operator==` and `compare()` methods for that purpose. For example: `if (line.compare(0, 5, "Part ") == 0) { ... }` or `istringstream iss(line); string word; iss >> word; if (word == "Part") { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to stop the file at a given line. But how do I start from where I stopped? The edited version is as follows:

```
ifstream in("C:\\Users\\Nusrat\\Desktop\\Subtraction.txt");
         if(!in) {
            cout << "Cannot open input file";
            return 1;
        }

        string line;

        while(getline(in, line))
        {
            cout<<line<<endl;
            while(line == "Now it is your turn to work out exercises!")
            {
                continue;
            }
```